# ASP.NET and jQuery Remote Validation: Validation function not called

Tags: asp.net, jquery-validation-engine

I have this client function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var validate = $("#<%=Page.Form.ClientID%>").validate({
        errorElement: 'span',                
        rules: {
            <%=txtMemberShipNumber.ClientID %> : {
                        required: true,
                        remote: function () {
                            return {
                                url: "/TestForm.aspx/IsMembershipNumberValid",
                                type: "POST",
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                dataType: "json",
                                data: JSON.stringify({ value: $('#<%=txtMemberShipNumber.ClientID %>').val() }),
                                dataFilter: function (data) {
                                    var msg = JSON.parse(data);
                                    if (msg.hasOwnProperty('d'))
                                        return msg.d;
                                    else
                                        return msg;
                                }
                            }
                        },
                    },
                },
                messages: {
                    <%=txtMemberShipNumber.ClientID %> : {
                        required: "Account number is Required",
                        remote: "Invalid",
                    },
                },
                onkeyup:false,
                onblur: true,
                onfocusout: function (element) { $(element).valid() }
 });
```

})

... that validates this control:

```
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$txtMemberShipNumber" type="text" id="MainContent_txtMemberShipNumber" class="textboxStyle" placeholder="Membership Number" />
```

The problem is the validation code is never called.  I've tested it in Firefox and Chrome.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

Instead of

> <%=txtMemberShipNumber.ClientID %> : {

... you should use

> <%=txtMemberShipNumber.**UniqueID**%> : {